# EF 5.0 Database first, POCO types and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm not much of a DB guy and I'm pretty new to EF.  I am confused by the erratic behavior of lazy loading on FK relationships.

Let's say I have a table Parent and a table Children.  Children has a non-unique FK into Parent.  Now some code:

```
Parent GetParent(int parentId)
{
    return Entities.Parents.Single(p => p.ParentId == parentId);
}

Child GetChildByName(int parentId, string name)
{
    var parent = GetParent(parentId);
    return parent.Children.Single(c => c.Name == name);   
}
```

Now, sometimes the call to `parent.Children.Single` will fail because the sequence `Parent.Children` is empty.  Not *always*, but *sometimes*, which  makes this terribly frustrating.  When it does fail I have verified via Intellitrace that no SQL call to fetch `Children` has executed.

This relationship is already created correctly in the database and all input parameters are correct.
If I use `Include("Children")` and eagerly load all Children it will of course work every time.

If I throw a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in after I get the Parent but before I filter for a Child, the Children will more often than not be loaded and the call succeeds.

So, as far as I can tell, this is a timing related issue.  FK relationships are not being loaded on demand, but they are being loaded at seemingly arbitrary times.  I don't understand this behavior and I assume that I must be missing something.

I really don't want to add `Include("SomeFK")` everywhere as it makes my code more brittle and, really, why should I have to do that?  If I have to sprinkle calls to `Include` all over the place I am

A) Grabbing data I often don't need
B) Writing code which I must edit whenever I add or remove relationships
C) Not getting much (aside from trivial code generation) out of my ORM.  I may as well be writing raw SQL calls at this point.

So yeah, I must be missing something, but I've looked and have not been able to find a comprehensive explanation of lazy loading using POCO types (database first!) for EF.

Comment: @kirsteng: The problem is that there *are* children, in the database, they're just not being loaded every time I ask for them via the Parent table. Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't.  Like I said, if I eagerly load them everything is fine.

Comment: Can you check what type is the `parent` when the exception occurs? It should be a runtime created type derived from your `Parent` class otherwise lazy loading will not work. That would be the first hint. Then check what is context configuration (if lazy loading and proxy creation are enabled) and if all navigation properties in your parent class are virtual.

Comment: Can you post the definition for Parent?  Is Children a virtual property?

Comment: Oops - accidentally deleted my comment which was
- Is the problem only occurring when there are no Children?  If so try using .SingleOrDefault instead of .Single, so you get a null return when there are no children.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: No, not virtual.  I have read about marking properties as virtual as to enable lazy loading via proxies, but as far as I am aware that is a code-first feature only.  I am using DB first and cannot change the generated class definitions.  My major source of confusion stems from the fact that I can run this code N times and it will work some fraction of N, and not work in the other attempts.  I'd like to understand exactly what EF is doing.

Comment: @kirsteng: I answered that above.  It's not a question of avoiding a crash.  I want the crash because that collection should *not* be empty.  `null` is not an acceptable return value in this case.  I know the data exists.

Comment: OK, I missed that Db-first. But how are these classes POCO?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's another question I perhaps should have asked.  Using VS2012 the default template is the POCO model (as far as I could tell anyway).  Perhaps I screwed up and should go regenerate using the heavyweight Entity types?  I've considered it, but I've had a hard time finding resources on DB first EF design.

Comment: Is your Context being disposed in the time that you are waiting? How and where are you initializing the context?

Comment: @qujck: The context is created when I create an instance of my data layer and is never disposed (well, not until the data layer instance is, but I only ever create one in the app;'s lifetime, so think of it as a singleton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was my own dumb fault. Of course, the bug was in my code, not a library used by thousands of developers.

I didn't provide enough information in the question.  I’ll leave out the minor details, but the root cause is a race condition.

I am creating/loading entity objects via a context created on thread A.  They are then passed to functions which spool up a new thread (B) and do their thing.  The call to the navigation property is eventually performed on thread B.

It is clear from reading the documentation that contexts are not thread safe.  From what I can glean, EF is performing lazy loading on the thread that the context was created on, i.e., thread A.

This is why the Thread.Sleep() seems to “fix” the issue; thread B is idling for a second while the main thread gets a chance to fill in the nav properties.

In our code, the main thread is busy performing a bunch of UI updates right after the call to the asynchronous function is called, so it blocks the context from doing its thing.  Performing everything synchronously works just fine.

Hopefully this helps someone who runs into a similar situation someday.  As the old adage goes, RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this has to do with the Entities object you have in the Parent method. Could it be that the Entities object is disposed or unavailable so that, while the Parent object is grabbed, the child is not because the Entity is disposed before the Lazy Loading can take place?

I'd recommend with a code pattern like this to get your objects with explicit loading if you're going to retrieve them outside of the scope of the Entity Context. Otherwise with the context gone, the object will be unable to lazy load? Not 100% on this but it's why I always explicitly load when I am returning records without the DbContext object available.

Comment: Nope, the context is alive and well for the life of the application.  Thanks though.  I realize that eager loading is a solution, just an ugly one that forces me to write code which is intolerant to changes on the DB side.

Comment: Doesn't have to be intolerant! You could easily write your own EagerLoad extension method that uses reflection to dynamically load virtual children. That way if you add/remove a column or collection or whatever, you don't need to know all the 'magic strings' of those columns, you can just let reflection do its work.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I am just holding out for true lazy loading until I am sure it is not an option.